# Getting a file with wget when the filename may change slightly

Tags: bash, shell-script, wget

I have a program that takes data from five government sources and merges them into one large database for my company.  I use wget to retrieve the files.  However I have discovered that one of the sources changes the name every time it is updated.

For example, the last time I got the file it was called `myfile150727.flatfile`.  Today when I tried to run my program I got exit status 8 `no such file`.  When I manually got into the ftp I found that the file is now called `myfile150914.flatfile`.  So obviously the filename is changing based upon the date it was last updated.

Can I modify my script to take this fact into account and still automatically download the file?

Comment: why then use wget if you have ftp ? if ftp is working from unix plateform you should use it, it is quiet scriptable and allow wildcard get (e.g. get myfile*.fileflat)

Comment: I'm not a bash scripter.  I'm a c++ programmer, so I'm just picking up the bash I need along the way.  Please, tell me more about this ftp wildcard get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but the details depend on how the file's name changes. If it is always today's date, just tell your script to get that:

```
filename=myfile"$(date +%y%m%d)".flatfile
wget ftp://example.com/"$file"
```

Or, if it is not updated daily and there is only one file called `myfileWHATEVER.flatfile`, get that:

```
wget "ftp://example.com/myfile*.flatfile"
```

If you can have many files with similar names, you could download all of them and then keep only the newest:

```
wget -N "ftp://example.com/myfile*.flatfile"
## Find the newest file
for file in myfile*.flatfile; do
    [[ "$file" -nt "$newest" ]] && newest="$file";
done
## Delete the rest
for file in myfile*.flatfile; do
    [[ "$file" != "$newest" ]] && rm "$file"
done
```

Alternatively, you can extract the date from the file name instead:

```
wget -N "ftp://example.com/myfile*.flatfile"
for file in myfile*.flatfile; do
    fdate=$(basename "${file//myfile}" .flatfile)
    [[ "$fdate" -gt $(basename "${nfile//myfile}" .flatfile) ]] && nfile="$file"
done
for file in myfile*.flatfile; do
    [[ "$file" = "$nfile" ]] || rm "$file"
done
```

Note that the above will keep multiple files if more than one have the same modification date.

Comment: Your code based on the modification time is more complex than what's needed here: the file names are ordered by time. Using file names is potentially more robust in case an old data dump is updated for some reason.

Comment: @Gilles `stat -c %Y` compares modification, not creation times. The `-c` is a GNU flag which is equivallent to `--format`. It has nothing to do with **c**reation. Your change to `stat -m` breaks the script since there's no `-m` switch, at least on GNU `stat`. As for the modification times, yes, I could compare them but I think it is likelier to have a file uploaded with the wrong name than to have an old one modified. Plus, I happened to have a similar script lying about already :)

Comment: Woops, sorry, brain fart. P.S. You could use the `-nt` operator of `test` instead of parsing times, it would make your script portable outside Linux and even to dash (`test -nt` is one of its few extensions to POSIX). Regarding the use of the name, it's likely that the file name is generated by the data generation process whereas the file mtime indicates when the file was produced or copied, so the file name is far more likely to be reliable.

Comment: @Gilles ooh, nice, I didn't know about `-nt`, thanks! I also added a version based on the file's name so the OP can choose.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you!  My situation was actually the third of the four cases you described.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
for site in site1.com site2.com
do
   mkdir -p $site
   ftp -in <<EOF
   connect $site
   user archemar foo
   lcd $site
   cd /path/to/remote/file
   mget myfile*.fileflat
   quit
EOF
done
```

- replace `user archemar foo` by your username and password, or `user ftp` if annonymous ftp is allowed.
- replace `cd /path/to/remote/file` by the obvious
- this will place misc *.flatfile in corresponding site dir. If name are unique, remove `mkdir $site` and `lcd $site`.
- according to your update process, you may wish to `rm` before transfer.